# How much should be the bleed area for a banner?

Tags: print-design, bleed

How much bleed area should I keep for a banner size of 760*1200 mm in Corel Draw or Illustrator any of the two or both?

Comment: Ask the printer.

Comment: Is it a pull-up banner or a normal banner? Pull-up banners need a lot more than a few centimeters on top and bottom because these 2 areas are rolled around the banner frame... Check the specification or templates on the printer's website in that case. Otherwise: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-can-i-determine-how-much-bleed-to-use/55907#55907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cutting of banners is more artesanal than lets say some flyers, you do not have a paper cutter board, but a razor. Sometimes is cutted by hand.

So you need to leave more than the average bleed for printing. I would say 1-1.5cm is ok.

You can ask for the borders to be folded and ironed to the back side. You really do not need more that this 1 cm, becouse, although this folding can be several centimiters width, depending on the banner's size, they can simply leave a blank space of another 4 cm arround.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, industry standard for printing at any size is a 3mm bleed or 1/8 on an inch. Although if you are getting it printed professionally, I would ask the person printing it as it may vary.