# How to prepare margins in Photoshop for A4 printing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, crop, bleed

I have created new image in Photoshop by selecting A4 template:

[image]

And my image has borders such as:

[image]

I am about to print it to A4 paper at a commercial printer.

Now I understand that printers have these paper grabbers and they need a little bit of margin. If that is true, how much should I increase size of canvas in order to make fit?

Comment: Depends on your printer, you can let the pronter just crop your image though.

Comment: @joojaa as you can see, if my image would be cropped, then I would lose borders at the top of the document (see screenshot in the question). So I imagine I should increase size of canvas and the question is, how much increase is required?

Comment: @Kunok are you talking about commercial printing or "borderless" printing using a home/office printer?

Comment: @Kunok you do that in a commercial printer that then cuts pages to size but if you have a office/home printer then nothing will actually make the printer fit your paper, you only option is to cut that page later. So you want to actually make your photoshop page smaller. By how much you need to read the printers manual on that.

Comment: @joojaa Are you telling me that I do not need to adjust it if I am printing it with commercial printer? (at printing office)

Comment: @Cai Commercial printer.

Comment: @Kunok Well in that case you need to make the image bigger but not move your graphic further it just needs to extend beyond your page. This allows allows for the cutter to have some offset. Its called bleed and makes it a duplicate of one of the many bleed questions but start by reading:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "grabbers" you refer too aren't something you need to worry about. The printer (the person, not the machine) will print your artwork on sufficiantly oversized stock. All you need to worry about is supplying your artwork with enough [bleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing)) so that your print can be trimmed to the correct size after printing. The amount of bleed you need is something you should discuss with your printer (again, the person), different printers require different amounts.

If you don't know before hand then a good starting amount is 3mm or 1/8 inch (possibly more, but certainly no less than that—too much bleed is no problem, not enough will be).

You can find a much more in-depth explination of bleed in this previous Q&A:
[How can I determine how much bleed to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-can-i-determine-how-much-bleed-to-use/55907#55907)

---

Not entirely relevant, but if you're using an A4 preset in Photoshop you can set up some guides for your bleed pretty easily:

1. Pull some guides to each edge of your page (they should snap in to place)

   [image]
2. Increase your canvas by the required amount. Setting the numbers to relative makes this much easier. For a 3mm bleed add 6mm to each axis.

   [image]

3. You now have guides set for your work area. Your artwork should extend all the way to the edge of the canvas, but anything outside of the guides will be trimmed.

[image]

Comment: You might add that the grabbers are not designers concern, the designer does not need to add space for them. Just making enough picture, for bleed, so thay can cut things in shape the printshop will choose a aoversized stock for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can layout your image edge to edge (ensuring to use the desired destination image revolution eg. A4 and 300DPJ)

You simply use **‘Shink to fit”** option when printing (commercial or home) this will ensure *no cropping* and it will let the printer correctly calculate the amount of boreder or bleed within its own margin area.

If you DO decide to add your own bleed- always leave the file at the *destination resolution* (ie A4) you **DO NOT** add bleed to increase the amount of pixels of the file- that is counter intuitive and ensures there will definitely be cropping UNLESS again you simply **use ‘shrink to fit’** in the printing options.

This can be requested at most (if not all printer shops) and most definitely on home printers.

Comment: Not really sure I understand this suggestion. In all my years, artwork is provided to any production house *at size* and they should *never* be using any "shrink to fit' option. Using such an option changes desired type sizes as well as other elements. This, to me, sounds merely like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: A bleed actually means there *should* be cropping. (or even *must* be cropping)