# How much bleed should I put on social media images?

Tags: bleed

I'm using the guidelines for social media images, but I notice that I have to take into account  some borders and so on. What is standard bleed for online images? 5px, 10px?

Guide is here:

http://sproutsocial.com/insights/social-media-image-sizes-guide/#facebook

Comment: Bleed is a print-only requirement, nothing to do with web work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None. Bleed is exclusively needed for print work. It is needed for inconsistencies in trimming so that you don't see paper edges when the artwork is trimmed.

See [How can I determine how much bleed to use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/55905/52050)

The Facebook image size guides you're reading have a range of sizes with different base sizes to the sizes they're shown at because the same image is used in a number of places at different sizes (those sizes change on a regular basis too) and are cropped in various ways; but that has nothing to do with "bleed".