# Preparing In Design facing pages bleed and color for print

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, color-conversion, blending

Hi guys I have a problem with my printer complaining all the time that the images in my doc are RGB and bleeds are not good.

Do you know how to check if all my images are Cmyk and how to set up bleed marks just outside of the document on facing pages?

Every time I try to set up crop marks I get this [image: bleeds between the pages]

Comment: From what I can see on your screenshot, I'm afraid you don't fully understand what bleed is. Please read this carefully: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-can-i-determine-how-much-bleed-to-use. About the RGB issue, it all depends of what PDF preset export you use. I will always recommend asking the printer to provide THEIR preferred preset.

Comment: That image shows **no bleed**, only trim.

Answer (score 1):

In the PDF Export dialog box:

- choose the 'High Quality Print' or 'PDF X1-a' preset from the preset dropdown at the top
- make sure the 'Spreads' option is NOT checked, and you are exporting in single page mode
- in the Marks and Bleeds tab, tick the 'All Printer's Marks' and 'Use Document Bleed Settings'

Comment: thanks for the reply Lucain, but I still have the bleed on the inner side !?   My document is a booklet two page, with facing pages. Now when I put crop marks it takes the belled from the inner side of the page too.  Also, the info for the linked images says ICC Profile: Document RGB .   Any ideas of hoe two make this ready for print. ? Thanks

Comment: @GocePetrov You shouldn't worry about the bleed appearing on the inner (binding) side. Depending on the binding, the printer should eliminate it when imposing the pages (if saddle-stitched), or when pages are trimmed (if perfect-bound).